# Editing specific elements of axis ticks in R - ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can you adjust specific x-axis tick labels with ggplot?

In the example below, the numbers specify an "upper grouping", of which each subsequent letter is part of. The axis represents categorical variables. So, to highlight this, I would like the numbers to be bolded and a little bigger in size. But I only found options that apply to the whole axis.

```
        scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:12,
                 labels = c("1", "A", "B", "2", "C", "D", "3", "E", "F", "G", "4", "H"))
```

(E.g., Group 1 has variables A and B, Group 2 has variables C and D, and so on)

Answer (score 1):

Use a vector argument in `element_text()` when setting the theme:

```r
library(ggplot2)

qplot(1:12, 1, geom = "point") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:12, labels = letters[1:12]) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(
    face = rep(c("bold", "plain", "plain"), 4),
    size = rep(c(12, 10, 10), 4)
  ))
```

[image]

Created on 2019-09-04 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).